# MDX COUNT ON FILTERED SET

Tags: filter, count, mdx

I have an employee dimension (22k rows) which has attribute [country],[region]. my fact table [LastAccess]is simple, just loggin data of employee, the measurement [RowCount] is row count. I want to count how many employee logged in the site twice [Two visits], five times [Five Visits],more than five [More Visits] during period of time, group by region and country. In the SQL, I used a temp table to count the visits for each employee, then use query like to display :

```
 SUM(IIF([Visits]=2,1,0)) AS [TwoVisits],   
 SUM(IIF([Visits]=5,1,0)) AS [FiveVisits],
 SUM(IIF([Visits]>5,1,0)) AS [MoreVisits],    
 FROM @EmployeeVisits EVPM
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblEmployeeData] ED ON EVPM.[AltEmployeeId] = ED.         [AltEmployeeId]
```

### GROUP BY ED.[BusinessRegion], ED.[CountryCode] )

The result should be like this:

```
Region  Country  TwoVisits   FiveVisits   More Visits
1     US          1261        1054         913    
2    IN          1829        1576         1441    
3    GB          344          281         237
```

I worked out some query like this :

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[twoVisits] AS 
case when ([Measures].[Last Access 1 Count]) =2
    then 1
    else 0
end
MEMBER [Measures].[twoVisitsCount] AS
SUM([Employee].[Alt Employee Id].[Alt Employee Id].Members, [Measures].    [twoVisits])

SELECT  
{[Measures].[twoVisitsCount]}ON 0,
NON EMPTY ({[Employee].[Business Region].&    [1],[Employee].[Business Region].&[2],[Employee].[Business Region].&[3]},
{[Employee].[Country Code].[Country Code].Members}) ON 1
FROM 
 (
     select(
        {[Employee].[Status Id].&[1],[Employee].[Status Id].&[3],[Employee].[Status Id].&[4]},          
        {[Employee].[Employee Type].&[13],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[29],
        [Employee].[Employee Type].&[9],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[25],
        [Employee].[Employee Type].&[5],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[1],
        [Employee].[Employee Type].&[14],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[30],
        [Employee].[Employee Type].&[10],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[26],
        [Employee].[Employee Type].&[6],[Employee].[Employee Type].&[2]},
        {[Date].[Date Key].&[20160801]:[Date].[Date Key].&[20160803]}
        ) on 0
FROM [OLAP Prep]
)
```

But after long running , it gave me this:

```
        twoVisitsCount

1   CA  36651
1   CL  36651
1   CO  36651
1   CR  36651
1   DO  36651
1   EC  36651
1   GT  36651
1   HN  36651
1   KY  36651
2   AU  36651
2   BD  36651
2   CN  36651
2   HK  36651
2   ID  36651
2   IN  36651
2   JP  36651
2   KR  36651
3   99  36651
3   AE  36651
3   AL  36651
```

All break down count are same.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this calculation as follows.

```
MEMBER [Measures].[twoVisitsCount] AS
SUM(Existing [Employee].[Alt Employee Id].[Alt Employee Id].Members, [Measures].    [twoVisits])
```

Your calculation looped across all employees. Adding the keyword `Existing` will only loop across employees in that business region and country.